# Teradata: how to remove part of a string after special character

Tags: sql, string, teradata

I have list of string values like this

```
32HK9932GH
223943201
ISAO0-32135950142
9320WS0342/11
```

for all rows where appliable, i need to remove the "/" character, and everything that goes after it

how to do that? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '^[^/]*')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `substring`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col,0,POSITION('/' IN col)) FROM table
```

Comment: Some syntax & logic issues with this answer.